# Difference between Enumerator and Enumeration in java

Tags: java, collections

Can any one please give clarification about these? I am really confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enumeration is process of loop through the collection ([Enumeration](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/enumeration)) (Generally called as Enumerator).

[Enums](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) are different.

> An enum type is a type whose fields consist of a fixed set of constants

Comment: Perhaps you should also mention that the generic Enumeration class is deprecated, as we speak of a Java scope. He might be confused about these.

Answer (score 1):

`Enumeration` is an interface :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html

> An object that implements the Enumeration interface generates a series
>   of elements, one at a time. Successive calls to the nextElement method
>   return successive elements of the series.

Enumerators are a generic term. More of on the lines of Iterator.

Answer (score 0):

`Enum` - Define a set of constants and use it where ever required.

`java.util.Enumeration` helps iterate through a set of objects using `.nextElement()`.